# Why passing string to scanf() compiles fine in C?

Tags: c, scanf, undefined-behavior

I recently wrote a simple program where I by mistake use scanf() instead of printf() for displaying a message on console. I was expecting to get compile time error, but it compiles fine without warnings & crashes at runtime. I know that scanf() is used for taking input from keyboard. Shouldn't I get an error in following program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    scanf("Hello world");   // oops, It had to be printf()
    return 0;
}
```

Is it invokes undefined behavior(UB)? Is there any mention about this in C standard? Why it isn't checked at compile time whether proper & valid arguments are passed to scanf() function or not?

Comment: Cannot reproduce crash. The program runs fine for me.

Comment: The code looks correct for me, and should complete normally when compiled and run. How do you know it 'crashes'? What are the crash symptoms?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the grammar implied: without failing to compile and *without* crashing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is behaving correctly. Indeed, `scanf` is declared

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

Luckily, your `format` does not contain any `%` for which there would be no correspondence in `...`, which would invoke UB.
Further, `format` is a string literal which allows the compiler to go through it ensuring you passed the right type of parameters in regards to the format specifiers, as part of sanity checks enabled with higher warning levels. (-Wformat family)

Answer (score 6):

Passing a string to `scanf` compiles fine, because `scanf` **expects** a string as it first parameter. See the documentation or programming manual for detailed `scanf` description.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler cannot read your mind.

Both `printf("Hello world")` and `scanf("Hello world")` are well-formed.

Answer (score -1):

[`scanf` does take a string paramater](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).  That's why it compiles fine, but it appears that your parameter does not match what it expects, so it crashes (or just exits) at runtime.

Comment: I really doubt it crashes... Why would it? `scanf` just reads characters from input and compares them to the format string. When comparision fails, `scanf` returns with some error – but does not 'crash'.